# What is the extent of Frylock's powers?

Tags: aqua-teen-hunger-force

I remember him having laser eyes, and maybe some form of telepathic powers, but what's the full range of his powers?

[image: An image of Frylock shooting electricity out of his eyes]

Comment: http://aqua-teen-hunger-force.wikia.com/wiki/Frylock

Comment: Does being the only one of the three with a brain count as a power?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frylock is shown to have the following powers:

---

**Eye Related**

- Laser vision, as most commonly show and seen in the opening credits
- Fire suppression, shown the episode "Dusty Gozongas"
- Fire Vision, shown in the episode "Hands on a Hamburger"
- Ice Vision, shown in the episode "The Clowning"

---

**Other**

- Flying, he is always shown to be hovering as well.
- Super intelligence
- Frydar (TM), this is fry that bends out a 90 degree angle.